# Como puedo hacer para que una columna de mi tabla sea el resultado de otras 2?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

estoy haciendo un programa de contabilidad con Python y Tkinter, usando una base de dates SQLite 3.

```
CREATE TABLE "balance" (
"id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"cuenta"    TEXT NOT NULL,
"debe"  REAL NOT NULL,
"haber" REAL NOT NULL,
"deudor"    REAL NOT NULL,
"acreedor"  REAL NOT NULL,
"activo"    REAL,
"pasivo"    REAL,
"positivo"  REAL,
"negativo"  REAL);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que, si el debe es mayor que el haber que vaya a saldo deudor, y si es mayor el haber que vaya a acreedor. Pero que se auto rellene, la idea del programa es seleccionar el rubro, por ejemplo Caja, y poner cuanto monto de debe y haber. y que las otras columnas se rellenen solas dependiendo del rubro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes triggers de la seguiente manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER debe_mayor_haber
         AFTER INSERT
            ON balance
          WHEN NEW.debe > NEW.haber
BEGIN
    UPDATE balance
       SET deudor = NEW.debe
     WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER debe_menor_haber
         AFTER INSERT
            ON balance
          WHEN NEW.debe < NEW.haber
BEGIN
    UPDATE balance
       SET acreedor = NEW.debe
     WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Comment: Me olvide de poner en la pregunta, que si uno es mayor que el otro, que vaya la diferencia nomas a esa tabla. Como seria el query?

Comment: Solo tendrías que cambiar el update, sería update balance set deudor =( new.debe-new.haber) where id=new.id; y para el acreedor la misma lógica.